# Variable data not being passed to subroutines with the .get() command

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, submit, subroutine

So I want to add data to an SQL Database by using the `SELECT` command within a GUI.

```
main_program()

    APID1=StringVar()
    APName1=StringVar()
    APDesc1=StringVar()

    def createnewproduct(): 
            def APSubmitDetails():
                db = sqlite3.connect('File')
                cursor = db.cursor()
                ProductID = APID1.get()
                ProductName = APName1.get()
                ProductDesc = APDesc1.get()

                cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO ProductTable(ProductID, ProductName, ProductDesc)
                VALUES(:ProductID, :ProductName, :ProductDesc)''',
            {'ProductID':ProductID,'ProductName':ProductName,'ProductDesc':ProductDesc})



            #Deletes all the widgets in the screen and then recreates the title/buttons.
            for widget in pwindow.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()



            APID=Label(pwindow, text = "Product ID: ").place(x=155, y=100)
            APIDA=Entry(pwindow, textvariable=APID1).place(x=225, y=100)
            APName=Label(pwindow, text ="Name : " ).place(x=155,y=125)
            APNameA=Entry(pwindow, textvariable=APName1).place(x=225, y=125)
            APDesc=Label(pwindow, text ="Desc : " ).place(x=155,y=150)
            ACDesc=Entry(pwindow, textvariable=APDesc1).place(x=225, y=150)
            ACSubmit=Button(pwindow, text="Submit", command= APSubmitDetails).place(x=190, y=175)


            labelspare=Label(pwindow,text ="Would you like to Query the Current Product Table or create a New Product Record?").place(x=10,y=10)
            CWbutton1=Button(pwindow,text="Current Product",command = searchforproduct).place(x=100,y=40)
            CWbutton2=Button(pwindow,text="New Product", command = createnewproduct).place(x=300,y=40)


    pwindow = Tk()
    pwindow.geometry("500x600")
    pwindow.title("Product")
    labelspare=Label(pwindow,text ="Would you like to Query the Current Product Table or create a New Product Record?").place(x=10,y=10)

    PWbutton1=Button(pwindow,text="Current Product",command = searchforproduct).place(x=100,y=40)
    PWbutton2=Button(pwindow,text="New Product", command = createnewproduct).place(x=300,y=40)

    pwindow.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Apollo Blinds")
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("1024x800")
main_program()
root.mainloop()
```

Firstly, it load up two buttons. Once the `createnewproduct():` button is chosen, It should then clear all widgets and load up the new labels, buttons and entry boxes. Once the data has been entered into there and the submit button is clicked, It should load the `defSubmitDetails():` and retrieve the data that had been stored in the entry boxes under the names e.g APID1 and load them into the database.

The problem I am having is I believe the `APID1.get()` command isn't working as it should and is not getting the data I entered into the entry boxes in the subroutine before. Therefore, It just enters " " into the file, not the data I had entered. Any suggestions on how to pass this data to the `def APSubmitDetails():` subroutine?

Comment: The indentation of this code is very screwy. Are you certain this is how your code is formatted? Is that first "for" loop part of APSubmitDetails?  is `pwindow = Tk()` really inside `def createnewproduct(): `? Are you really trying to create the instances of `StringVar` before creating the root window?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The formatting was a little off. Also, the reason it loads a new window for this subroutine is because all the code is inside a subroutine called `main_program` which contains other subroutines too, but are unrelated which is why I didn't include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that you are creating two instances of `Tk`. A tkinter application must have exactly one instance of `Tk`, and should call `mainloop()` exactly once. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.